# Direct Handoff or BlockingQueue for I/O Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, io, buffer

If I have an I/O thread using a `FileChannel`, should I have a method that takes a value, fills a buffer and writes it to the disk, or should I have a bounded queue with a cache that writes blocks to the disk instead?

The values are rather small, and there is going to be a lot of them, so from a performance standpoint, should I make a wrapper for the `FileChannel` to make it similar to `BufferedWriter`? Or is direct handoff and write ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have an I/O thread using a FileChannel, should I have a method that takes a value, fills a buffer and writes it to the disk, or should I have a bounded queue with a cache that writes blocks to the disk instead?

Depends a little on the characteristics of your application.  If you are doing some processing of the information, then you might be processor bound so forking a thread to just do the IO to the `FileChannel` while consuming from a bounded `BlockingQueue` would be a good idea.  But CPU speeds still dramatically outflank IO so the complexity of the multiple threads may not be a noticeable win.

If you do use a `BlockingQueue`, make sure to limit its size otherwise the producer might fill up memory if it produces faster than the writer.

> The values are rather small, and there is going to be a lot of them, so from a performance standpoint, should I make a wrapper for the FileChannel to make it similar to BufferedWriter?

Yes.  Given that each of the values is small, writing one per `FileChannel` IO operation is going to be expensive.  Buffering a number of values and then writing them as a block *should* give you a good performance increase.  Certainly worth writing the buffer and testing it.